# Отправка данных из Applet методом post

Tags: applet, java, отладка

Здравствуйте) 
Есть апплет и сервлет. Апплет служит для входа в систему и передает сервлету данные (логин,пароль). 
В апплете делал так:

```
URL url1 = new URL("http://localhost:8080/WebApplication/servlet");    
URLConnection connect = url1.openConnection();  
connect.setUseCaches(false);  
connect.setDoOutput(true);  
String data = URLEncoder.encode("x", "UTF-8") + URLEncoder.encode("wwooow", "UTF-8");
connect.setRequestProperty("Pragma", "no-cache");  
connect.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  
connect.setRequestProperty("Content-length", Integer.toString(data.length()));  
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(connect.getOutputStream());  
out.println(data);  
out.flush();  
out.close();
```

Но при этом у меня апплет остается, а мне надо чтобы апплет "переходил" на сервлет, так как сервлет выдает какие-то значение в виде html-страницы.

пробовал добавить в апплет:

```
applet.getAppletContext().showDocument(url1, "_self");
```

При этом осуществляется переход но параметры теряются.

Как передать из апплета параметры методом post при этом перейдя на сервлет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы определитесь, что вы хотите сделать. Вы хотите POST-запрос сделать из апплета или сделать POST-запрос из браузера. Если вам надо отобразить резальтат этого запроса в браузере, так вы и делайте запрос из браузера. Сделайте на странице с апплетом форму с методом POST, а из апплета ставьте значение полей формы и вызывайте отправку формы. Правда в этой схеме не совсем ясно, зачем тогда вам апплет.

Comment: апплет нужен для GUI , а именно JTree)

Comment: Ну если вы уверены, что апплет нужен, то делаете на странице с апплетом невидимую форму и из апплета заполняете её полня, а потом сабмитите эту форму. По-другому вы вряд ли можете сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно кому-нибудь пригодится) 
Незнаю делаю ли я правильно, но пока (тьфу-тьфу) все работает) 
Итак делаем на странице апплет, JavaScript, и простенькую html-форму со скрытыми полями)
В теге <applet>  надо указать параметр  name.
Из JS обращаемся к методам апплета :

```
document.имя_формы.имя_поля.value = document.имя_апплета.имя_метода();
```

потом отправляем форму методом post

```
имя_формы.submit();
```

P.S большое спасибо [[@cy6erGn0m](/users/335/cy6ergn0m)](/users/335/cy6ergn0m)